# Java DeleteMapping Method Not Allowed

Tags: java, spring

I'm trying to create an api to delete a certain ID from the storage;
Here's my code.

API Controller:

```
@DeleteMapping("{cId}")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public String delete(@PathVariable String cId) {
    compareService.delete(cId);

    return "redirect:/compare";
}
```

Service:

```
public void delete(String cId) {
    compareLogic.delete(cId);
}
```

Logic:

```
 public void delete(String cId){
        System.out.println("A: " + sessionModel.getCIds());
        List<String> update = sessionModel.getCIds();
        update.remove(new String(cId));
        System.out.println("B: " + sessionModel.getCIds());
      }
```

However when I execute the api it shows

```
{
success: false,
warning: false,
error: "405",
error_description: "Method Not Allowed"
}
```

Are there any possible reasons by just looking at the code?
Many thanks,

Comment: I think you are missing `/` in `@DeleteMapping("{cId}")`. So try using `@DeleteMapping("/{cId}")`.

Comment: @SudhirOjha Dear ,it is not the  problem , I already have added the answer , if you have a  time please look in to that thank you

Comment: @Tsao ,Have you resolved you problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just I have tired with simple code snippet , Could you please try to understand and (Try to follow my suggestion as well )

When you hit from browser side (**From Address Bar**), it won't work for POST/PUT/DELETE calls ,  it is actually working from browser, if you try to typing in address bar then it is a GET request then it will   not supported to the other format

Just I have added two screenshot I have tired with Browser and PostMan

**First I have tired with POSTMAN (it is working perfectly)**

[image]

**Second I have tired with Browser (It will throw not supported
exception )**

[image]

I have tired with small code snippet just copy from your code and remove element from list

```
@DeleteMapping("{cId}")
    public String delete(@PathVariable String cId) {
         List<String> arr=new ArrayList<String>(3);
         arr.add("A");
         arr.add("B");
         arr.add("C");
         arr.remove(cId);
         for (String string : arr) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }

        return "redirect:/compare";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is sending the request with a non-supported method. 405 Status Code indicates that the server doesn't support the method or verb sent in the request.
Could you also provide the API call details like HTTP method and relative path ? recheck your API details, make sure you are using correct HTTP method.